# Excel - finding duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I'm given a sheet with 2 columns and 17 rows. First column is populated with characters, 2nd one is empty. I have the following problem:

Using a single formula, detect all of the duplicates in the above list (1st column).  If the term (on each row) has already appeared in the list, then your formula should display it on the same row (2nd column), if the term has not already appeared on the list then your formula should display N/A (2nd column, same row)

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like homework so your not going to exercise your brain and learn how to solve problems by us giving you the answer.  Think it through - it's not that hard.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald It's not homework but thank you for your input :) I'm only posting because I have little experience with Excel. I have tried with Conditional Formatting but I only got to highlight the cells in a different color. It's not what I'm looking for tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your first column begins in cell A1, select the range B1:B17 and then click on the formula bar at the top and paste the formula:

```
=IF(1<COUNTIF(A$1:A1,A1),A1,"N/A")
```

Confirm with **CONTROL-ENTER**.

Comment: my first column begins in cell B2 through B17, I want to display them in C2:C17, I tried the formula but it did not work. Tried to edit as follows `=IF(1<COUNTIF(A$1:B2,B2),B2,"N/A")`

Comment: I now just tried =IF(MAX(COUNTIF(B$2:B$17;B2:B17))>1,B2,"N/A"), but again, no no result.

Comment: Here is the formula for your case:

Comment: =IF(1<COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2),B2,"N/A")

Comment: Edit - that worked, thanks alot. All I had to do was replace the , with ;

Comment: Fixed it, and actually understood how it worked as well, so a big, big thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is =IF(COUNTIF(B$2:B2,B2)=1,"N/A",B2).

Good luck!

Comment: just copying above answer is not good. You must give it your own or you can include more details with it atleast !